# Views which wrap like a float does in HTML?

Tags: android

Is there a way to get this behavior in android? Views which tile horizontally until they run out of space, and then flow to the next line.

Comment: What do you mean. Set the width to fill parent, and height to wrap_content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such layout in the UI toolkit. It would however be pretty easy for you to write one.